# A Linux thread without a stack

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, memory

Of course, it is necessary to have a stack of some sort - but what I want to do is have a (userland) thread where I have complete (or as near as possible to complete) control over memory allocation. What would be the best way to do this? I could avoid using automatic variables and use the heap for everything, I think: but is there a better way?

Comment: What's the idea behind this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  That might give us a better idea of what you want in a solution.

Comment: I think we have a typical case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: I suspect the goal here is to avoid memory allocations in various functions

Comment: Heap allocations are not more controlled than stack allocation.

Comment: A thread does not need a stack, it can also have a fixed amount of data it is operating on, including all data for local variables. You can extend that to functions, a call then involves allocating a record for the function's variables, return address and to store registers it needs to overwrite before jumping to the according address.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - 'A thread does not need a stack' - wh.. wh.. what?

Comment: Yes, Martin, do you have any arguments that contradict this or do you only have ridicule? Seriously, the stack common in C is one way to do things, but it's not the only one and in some cases not the best one either. Search for "stackless" here.

Comment: It's not Linux that requires a stack (though it gives you one by default when it starts a process), its the C compiler and language.  If you write your code is assembly, there's no need for a stack at all.  But if you use C, you're going to need to give the compiler something like a stack to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a loop at [Protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/), could be the thing you are looking for.

Out of interest what are you trying to do? Embedded platform?

Comment: I am looking to build a logical model of a multicore (NoC) platform, using the threads as analogues of the cores and having a fixed memory pool as the analogue of the physical memory of such a device. Thus I don't want to have the compiler allocate memory on my behalf - I want to do it all explicitly. Thanks for the answer, by the way, I'll have a look.